# Rails Logging API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

Is there some guide about logging in Rails? There doesn't seem to be an official guide about that topic. Does Rails have an own logging API, or does it internally use the Ruby logging system?

I am using Rails 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the docs, Rails uses the standard Ruby logger, you can work in log4r (or other) if you'd like: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger